# Does anyone know of a good reference/documentation/tutorial for the daap protocol?

Tags: itunes, protocols, daap

For those who hear it for the first time it stands for Digital Audio Access Protocol. It's what iTunes uses to stream music.

The protocol uses HTTP for passing around playlist info, streaming audio etc.

I've looked at the specifications, but there are a lot of things that are unclear. Does anyone have a link to better documentation of this protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your best bet: [Unofficial DAAP Protocol Documentation](http://tapjam.net/daap/)

Also, see the additional external links in the Wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Audio_Access_Protocol#External_links).

Comment: That's what I thought. Anyway thanx for the answer.